# RT-N66U trying to connect to VPN after server removal

Tags: networking, router, wireless-router, openvpn

A while ago, I set up my Asus RT-N66U itself as an OpenVPN client, effectively tunneling every client's traffic through the VPN.

Now, I have disabled the VPN client option (I removed the server's entry in the server list), however:

From the system log, it appears as though it's still trying to connect to the server. The below is printed over and over, about once every few seconds in the log. (I have replaced IP addresses and ports for obvious reasons.)

```
May 11 10:19:57 openvpn[5538]: [UNDEF] Inactivity timeout (--ping-restart), restarting
May 11 10:19:57 openvpn[5538]: SIGUSR1[soft,ping-restart] received, process restarting
May 11 10:19:57 openvpn[5538]: Restart pause, 2 second(s)
May 11 10:19:59 openvpn[5538]: Socket Buffers: R=[something->something] S=[something->something]
May 11 10:19:59 openvpn[5538]: UDPv4 link local: [undef]
May 11 10:19:59 openvpn[5538]: UDPv4 link remote: [AF_INET]my.server's.IP.here:portHere
```

Why is this happening? (And yes, I'm running the latest firmware)

Comment: Most consumer level routers provide either a software or hardware method of restoring the default settings, I suggest you reset your router, so it wipes the VPN information from the stored memory.

Comment: Have you rebooted the router after removing the entry?

Comment: @acejavelin - First thing I tried :)

Comment: @AndroidDev Honestly, I would factory default and setup again... And if your doing that switch to the current rMerlin firmware, it is an enhanced version of the stock firmware, very solid.

Comment: @acejavelin - I've considered resetting it, but what if I reset it, and then at some point in the future use the VPN ability again, and then the same thing happens?

Comment: @AndroidDev - You simply reset the router again?  You backup your current configuration and restore it?  How can we answer your "what-if" scenario if it hasn't happened yet?

Comment: @AndroidDev You will need to rebuild the VPN again anyway,  so what difference does it make? Plus, try the rMerlin firmware, it is stock with lots of bug fixes and enhancements, much more stable, and you have to reset anyway... You can always go back to purely stock